# How to force expand datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, input, datalist

There is an input and its datalist. If I enter **1111**, a list with matching values ​​will expand. 
But if I remove any character (except the last one), then the select list collapses as if there are no matching values.
Although if deployed manually, the result is correct.
How to make it not collapse or force it to expand?

```html
<input type="text" list="int"> 
<datalist id="int">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>111</option>
  <option>1111</option>
  <option>11111</option>
  <option>111111</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: In what browser do you observe this behavior? What do you mean by manually deployed?

Comment: @CodeManX
Google Chrome, Opera, Edge. By manual deployment, I mean clicking on the down arrow of the inbox

Comment: If you are referring to this behavior (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPxwR.gif): that's the browser's native behavior, and not something within your control in JavaScript unless you capture all input events and then dispatch your own and reposition the cursor for the user. You can file an issue with each browser vendor if you think the UX should be changed. (I agree with you.)